# Ruby on Rails: script/my_script vs rake my_namespace:my_task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-organization

How does one decide whether to put functionality in a `generator` like script or a `rake` (or `thor` task?

Some examples:

In `thinking-sphinx`, `rake ts:start` will start the `sphinx` daemon. But in `delayed_job`, `scipt/delayed_job start` will start the daemon. More or less same functionality (apparently) but different approaches.

Are there any obvious reasons for choosing between the two i.e., why was `script/generate model` was chosen over, say, `rake generate:model`

Answer (score 1):

In the past it has been a rather subjective matter. But today Rails 3 only has one file in the script directory (`rails`) so it's not the preferred place to put scripts anymore.

If you have a gem that needs to define one or more Rake tasks for a Rails app, the very best way is to add a Railtie to the gem ([Railtie docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html)) and use the `rake_tasks` method.

Answer (score 0):

I decide between the two based on whether I need to load the entire rails environment/app for the script to run. If so, then I make it a rake task.

For example, if my script needs to access database objects, or code I use in my app, then for sure, I'll make it a rake task. Otherwise, making it simply in `/script`, it'll run much faster. If you notice, things like `script/generate` don't need to look at your rails app, and so aren't rake tasks.